# Is there any way to solve this equation for $x$?: $\sum_{k\in K} e^k \left(\frac{a}{(1+be^{c(x+k)})}-d\right)=0$

Tags: summation, recreational-mathematics, approximation, problem-solving, approximation-theory

I'm trying to obtain the $x$ that satisfies the following equality where all pronumerals are constants except $k$ and $x$ but can't see a way to do it

$$\sum_{k\in K} e^k \left(\frac{a}{(1+be^{c(x+k)})}-d\right)=0$$

$K$ is an arbitrary finite subset of $\mathbb N$

Comment: What is $K$? Please clarify

Comment: An arbitrary finite set of natural numbers

Comment: Why are you expecting there to be some closed form solution to this?

Comment: I'm interested in how a solution should be attempted, even if it's numerically, given $K$ and constants

Comment: Closed form was only a hope, not realistically expected

Comment: Newton's method or fixed point iteration would probably be a good place to start for a numerical solution, especially since it's a finite sum so everything can easily be computed (assuming $K$ is not way too large)

Comment: You can simplify the equation. For example, when $K=\{1,2,3\}$, you get [this equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5Bexp%28k%29+%28a%2F%281%2Bb+e%5E%28c+x%2Bk%29%29-d%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C3%7D%5D) which can be rewritten as $a \left(\frac{e^3}{b e^3 w^c+1}+ \frac{e^2}{b e^2 w^c+1}+  \frac{e^3}{b e^3 w^c+1}\right)=d (e^3+e^2+e),e^x=w$ which has an elementary [closed form inverse](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+function+of++%28a+e%29%2F%281+%2B+b+e+w%5Ec%29+%2B+%28a+e%5E2%29%2F%281+%2B+b+e%5E2+w%5Ec%29+%2B+%28a+e%5E3%29%2F%281+%2B+b+e%5E3+w%5Ec%29)

Comment: @Lorago Fair enough, you don't reckon there'd be any nice closed-form approximations do you?

Comment: @TymaGaidash That WolframAlpha output did not solve for $w$. I'm not sure what it actually did.

Comment: @aschepler If we set $a,b,c$ to arbitrary constants, it does [invert](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+function+of+%28e+Khinchin%29%2F%281+%2B+e+π+w%5ECatalan%29+%2B+%28e%5E2+Khinchin%29%2F%281+%2B+e%5E2+π+w%5ECatalan%29+%2B+%28e%5E3+Khinchin%29%2F%281+%2B+e%5E3+π+w%5ECatalan%29) wrt to $w$. If we try with $K=\{1,2,3,4\}$, we can get a long inverse function

Comment: What is the sign of $b$ ? This is a key point.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici $b > 0$

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve (numerically) the equation
$$\sum_{k=i}^{k=j} e^k \left(\frac{a}{1+b\,e^{c(x+k)}}-d\right)=0$$ that is to say
$$\sum_{k=i}^{k=j}\frac{e^k}{1+b\,e^{ck}\,e^{c x}}=A \qquad \text{with} \qquad A=\frac d a\, \frac{e^{j+1}-e^i}{e-1}$$
$$y=e^{cx}\qquad \implies \qquad \sum_{k=i}^{k=j}\frac{e^k}{1+b\,e^{ck}\,y}=A$$

Now, the problem is totally different depending on the sign of $b$.

If $b>0$, there is no vertical asymptote and the lhs is a decreasing function of $y$ which will have a single solution if $d<a$ (otherwise, no solution).

If $b<0$ you will have something like $(j-i)$ vertical asymptotes and one root between each pair and one root after the largest asymptote.

If $b>0$, since
$$\sum_{k=i}^{k=j}\frac{e^k}{1+b\,e^{ck}\,y} < \sum_{k=i}^{k=j}\frac{e^k}{b\,e^{ck}\,y}=\frac{e^{-c i+c+i}-e^{-c j+j+1}}{b y( e^c -e)}$$ we have an upper bound for $y$ to be used as starting guess for Newton-like methods.